# How can I combine the output of 2 separate filters

Tags: jq

I'm querying the result of an AWS call that looks kind of like this:

```
{
    "SecretList": [
        {
            "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager....",
            "Name": "some-name",
            "Description": "",
            "LastChangedDate": "2021-06-03T20:43:35.059000-05:00",
            "LastAccessedDate": "2021-05-31T19:00:00-05:00",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "company-mnemonic",
                    "Value": "whatever"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "usage",
                    "Value": "something"
                }
            ]
         }
     ]
}
```

What I want is the ARN, Name and only the tag with the key "company-mnemonic". So far I've come up with 2 separate filters but I need to understand how I can combine them. Just getting ARN and Name is easy: `.SecretList[] | {ARN, Name}`. Querying the tags is tricky but I figured out this: `.SecretList[].Tags[] | select(.Key == "company-mnemonic") | {"company-mnemonic": .Value}`. Is there a way I can combine these 2 ideas into one so that I get something that looks like this:

```
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager....",
    "Name": "some-name",
    "company-mnemonic": "whatever"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not tricky at all. `Tags` can be converted to a proper object using `from_entries`, and then it's simple addition.

```
.SecretList[] | {ARN, Name} + (.Tags | from_entries | {"company-mnemonic"})
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/inifmdDPX6)</sup>